# Pseudorandomisation with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, random, psychopy

I currently have a problem with pseudorandomizing my trials. I am using a while loop in order to create 12 files containing 38 rows (or trials) that match 1 criterion:

1) max `color1expl` cannot be identical in 3 consecutive rows

Where `color1expl` is one of the columns in my dataframe.

When I have files of only 38 rows to create, the following script seems to work perfectly.

```
import pandas as pd

n_dataset_int = 0
n_dataset = str(n_dataset_int)

df_all_possible_trials = pd.read_excel('GroupF' + n_dataset + '.xlsx') # this is my dataset with all possible trials


# creating the files
for iterations in range(0,12): #I need 12 files with pseudorandom combinations

    n_dataset_int += 1 #this keeps track of the number of iterations
    n_dataset = str(n_dataset_int) 

    df_experiment = df_all_possible_trials.sample(n=38) #38 is the total number of trials
    df_experiment.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    #max color1expl cannot be identical in 3 consecutive trials (maximum in 2 consecutive t.)

    randomized = False

    while not randomized: #thise while loop will make every time a randomization of the rows in the dataframe
        experimental_df_2 = df_experiment.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) 
        for i in range(0, len(experimental_df_2)):
            try:
                if i == len(experimental_df_2) - 1:
                    randomized = True
                elif (experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i] != experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i+1]) or (experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i] != experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i+2])
                    continue
                elif (experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i] == experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i+1]) and (experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i] == experimental_df_2['color1expl'][i+2]):
                    break    
            except:
                pass

    #export the excel file
    experimental_df_2.to_excel('GroupF_r' + n_dataset + '.xlsx', index=False) #creates a new
```

However, when doing the same procedure increasing the number from `n=38` to `n=228`, the script seems to run for an indefinite amount of time. So far, more than one day and it did not produce any of the 12 files. Probably because there are too many combinations to try.

Is there a way to improve this script so that it works with a larger amount of rows?

Comment: `except: pass` seems like a really bad idea, why are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think this might be actually a problem? I am not that much into programming, so I might have made a mistake, but it seems to me that the loop runs until 12 files are produced, skipping all the errors. In the sense that if try does not work, the loop starts again, or not?

Comment: The issue isn't whether or not the program works, it's about catching all possible exceptions. You don't want your program silently throwing away exceptions like `MemoryError`, `OverflowError` and `OSError`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the way you use to generate random samples (pseudo-code):

```
n = 38 # or anything else

my_sample = []

my_sample.append( pop_one_random_from(df_all_possible_trials) )
my_sample.append( pop_one_random_from(df_all_possible_trials) )

while len(my_sample) < n:
  next_one = pop_one_random_from(df_all_possible_trials)
  if next_one is equal to my_sample[-1] and my_sample[-2]:
    put next_one back to df_all_possible_trials
    continue
  else:
    my_sample.append( next_one )
```

If I get it right, all the different samples (totalling number of combinations, 'len(df_all_possible_trials) choose n') have the same probability to be chosen, which is what you're looking for. And it should work faster.